# openconnect: connection destroyed after ls and unable to use sftp

Tags: networking, ssh, vpn, sftp, openconnect

In the past I have used Cisco AnyConnect under Mac OS to connect to a remote system at my uni. This worked perfectly.

Now I wish to do the same thing under Ubuntu 14.04, however Cisco AnyConnect has not been made available for this platform.

Instead, I have installed `network-manager-openconnect`, and was able to connect to the remote system successfully. However, there are two significant problems that stops me from working remotely:

1. I am unable to establish an SFTP connection using Filezilla.
2. The connection is destroyed/freezes whenever I `ls` directories containing more than a dozen or so files.

How do I resolve these two problems?

Or is there a workable alternative to 
openconnect that will allow me to connect in the same manner as Cisco AnyConnect?